# Shorten way to create multiple activities in Android - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My question is not about an error or an issue i'm facing.
Basically let's say you are creating a game of questions.
In the MainActivity you use `intent` to go to another activity which lets say its  `QuestionOneActivity` question 1.
Once you solve the question you would go to another question.
The other question is lets say `QuestionTwoActivity` and so on.
Now in Android you have to create a layout file and a Kotlin or Java class.
Is there any way to shorten all of this?

for example if you have 10 question that you have to create 10 classes and 10 layout files.

Comment: "Is there any way to shorten all of this?" -- have one layout per question *format* (multiple-choice, text entry, etc.). Have one fragment per question format that knows how to work with that layout. Have your questions be organized by format, so you can display the right fragment, and have the fragment know how to fill in the layout's widgets with the question data (e.g., the question itself and the various answers for a multiple-choice question).

Comment: No man you don't need to create 10 activities for the 1 activity is enough for the when the answer is correct change the question simple

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is where you would split out the content of your Activity from the logic of your Activity.

Create a generic activity that deals with the layout and any logic. Then have a separate Class that handles the actual questions (And perhaps the answers). These might be loaded in from some static list of variables or pulled dynamically from a server etc.

Then when you create you intent pass with it a parameter to state which question should be displayed.

Have logic in the generic question activity to select the correct question object and display it.